# Command not found: fork

Tags: macos, shell, fork

I am working on a Mac. I am trying to use the fork command to run another sh file on Terminal.app:

```
$ fork sh
bash: fork: command not found
```

What's wrong with my command?

Comment: Where did you read that there's a command called "fork"?

Comment: Please improve your question by posting a more complete example of what you're trying to do. I tried to guess in my edits, but you can continue to improve the example until it is more like what you're actually doing. Once you've edited your question, it's likely that it will be either re-opened or migrated to SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fork` isn't a shell function.

You can run an executable script directly `/path/to/script`.

You can `source`/`.` a script to run it in the current shell `. path/to/script`.

You can also run the shell directly on the script `bash /path/to/script`.

Answer (score 0):

To run a command in the background, you can put an ampersand (`&`) on the end.

So for example, if your command is `/path/to/some/program some args here`, you could run it in the background (and continue entering commands in your foreground shell) using:

```
/path/to/some/program some args here &
```